# CSS Grid layout not filled the last column at the first row when has availabe space

Tags: css, css-grid

For example, I've 6 number of checkbox, and I've specified 4 columns and 2 rows

```css
div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 20px;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>a</span>
  <span>b</span>
  <span>c</span>
  <span>d</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>f</span>
</div>
```

but the last column at the first row was empty, so how to let 'f' filled in the last columns?

expect result:

```
a c e f
b d
```

Answer (score 1):

Add grid-column-start to the last span child,

```css
div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 1rem;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}

 span:last-child{
 grid-column-start: 4;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>a</span>
  <span>b</span>
  <span>c</span>
  <span>d</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>f</span>
</div>
```